# Sort on merged columns without merging columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example Table:

```
id | val1 | val2
1  |   100|  50
2  |    90|  50
3  |    80|  50
4  |    70|  50
5  |    60|  91
6  |    50|  92
7  |    40|  93
8  |    30|  94
```

Expected Results:

```
id | val1 | val2
1  |   100|  50
8  |    30|  94
7  |    40|  93
6  |    50|  92
5  |    60|  91
2  |    90|  50
3  |    80|  50
4  |    70|  50
```

I'm trying to sort the table on some sort of merged columns, without actually merging the columns.  When I try something like `select * from exampletable order by val1 desc, val2 desc` it orders it by `val1` then only `val2` when there are repeat values in `val1`.

What I'd like it to do is order by a combination of both columns, but not repeat the `id` column.

Comment: And what combination is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this hearkens back to early programming problems. If I get your meaning, you're wanting to sort by the largest of the two columns. As such, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM example
ORDER BY
  CASE
    WHEN val1 > val2 THEN val1
    ELSE val2
  END
```